# How does this sheets formula enumerate gaps in a sequence?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a list of numeric keys for rows in a google sheet.
The keys are normally sequential but gaps occasionally appear.
I want to enumerate the missing keys in the sequence.

I came across this handy recipe https://support.google.com/docs/thread/5868559?hl=en&msgid=6240039

```
=filter(
    row(indirect("A"&A1&":A"&+sort(A1:A, 1, 0))),
    isna(match(row(indirect("A"&A1&":A"&+sort(A1:A, 1, 0))), A1:A,0))
 )
```

This works really well, but I dont *understand* why it works.

The first argument to 'filter' is supposed to be a range, but the output of 'row' is just a number. Adding 'sort' to the constructed string appears to work like a 'max' function, but when wrapped with 'indirect' turns into an array.

It seems like the filter function implementation operates in non-intuitive ways that might be easily explained, perhaps related to the range notations elsewhere in the argument expressions.

Can anyone elaborate on why this recipe works?  The original post is locked.

Comment: `=ROWS(...)` is just a number. Try `=ROW(1:3)` in a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what is hopefully a simpler approach to the above scenario. the `row+indirect+sort` part can be altered/condensed to `sequence(max(column))`

I've added the steps in the screenshot to depict whats happening at each step & in the final step we are filtering the values which xmatched with `#N/A` error

```
=let(Σ,sequence(max(A:A)),
    filter(Σ,isna(xmatch(Σ,A:A))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the Let() function!  Using it allows me to avoid temporary cells without repeating sub expressions throughtout my formulas as they become more complex

Answer (score 1):

An even more simple alternative:

```
=tocol(unique({A:A;sequence(max(A:A)},,1),1)
```

We are concatenating your list of numbers (with some missing) with a list of all numbers up to the maximum of your list, then using the *exactly once* argument of UNIQUE to return only those numbers which occur only once (which by definition are the missing ones).

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the unique() function as I didnt know it has the 'exactly_once' parameter which makes easier